# Do I need to change anything programmatically to leverage the integrated pipeline in IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, pipeline, integrated

Do I need to change anything programmatically to leverage the integrated pipeline in IIS7?

If so, what's the best way to degrade gracefully and remain functional on IIS6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the setting is in IIS when selecting application pool (integrated mode).
I recently upgraded from IIs 6.0 to IIS 7.0. The application runs fine on both IIS 6.0 and 7.0.